# javascript - check a radiobutton from a radiobutton group by it's value from code

Tags: javascript, html

i'm working on a project, and i need to check a radiobutton from a radiobutton group by it's value.

i have this radiobutton group.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="slect" id="optradio"  value="oriente" checked>=Orienté
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="slect" id="optradio" value="Nonoriente">Non orienté
</label>
```

in my code i have a variable, i manage to affect it to  one of two values

```
var x="Nonoriente"       or     var x="oriente"
```

My goal is to automatiquly check the équivalent value of x in the radiobuttons when an event is triggered.

Comment: `ID` should be used as a unique identifier. You're using it for two elements.

Comment: You should not have duplicate IDs in your HTML. Instead of checking by value (which is really unsafe), you should just give them a unique ID instead and select them using that. Even better: if you are toggling between two states, isn't it better to use **checkbox** instead? That is what this input control is designed for.

Comment: i already thought of that, but the situation in my project implies that i make the same id and name for both of them.

Comment: I can't stress this enough: you **cannot** duplicate IDs. Browser behaviour when it comes to handling multiple occurrences of the same ID is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, fix the elephant in the room: you cannot have duplicate IDs in your markup. It is not some arbitrary rule that we made up, but browser behaviour when handling duplicated ID is undefined. No project will *ever* require you to have duplicate IDs—that just means bad design.

If you want to select by value, the only way is to select all the radio buttons on the page that matches this selector: `input[type="radio"][value="Nonoriente"]`. Then you iterate through this node collection and set their `checked` property to true.

p/s: This approach is inefficient, but considering that you have mentioned restraints in your project, it might be the only viable solution.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][value="Nonoriente"]');

  for (i = 0; i < radioInputs.length; ++i) {
    radioInputs[i].checked = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="slect" id="optradio"  value="oriente" checked>Orienté
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="slect" id="optradio" value="Nonoriente">Non orienté
</label>

<button type="button" id="btn">Click to check nonoriente</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy with jQuery. Here are the docs for the [.prop() method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
if (x === Oriente) {
    $( input:first-of-type ).prop( "checked" );
} else {
    $( input:first-of-type ).prop( "checked" );
}
```

It might make it easier to assign unique ID's to each radio button and use those to access the .prop() method on the DOM element. (Semantically they should be unique anyways. If for some reason you want to apply anything to multiple DOM nodes you should be using a class.)

Native Javascript:

```
if (x === Oriente) { 
    document.getElementById('uniqueId1').checked = true; 
} else { 
   document.getElementById('uniqueId2').checked = true; 
}
```

Comment: unfortunally i'm not familiar with jquery, is there any solution by native javascript?

Comment: I edited the answer. Not robust enough formatting in comments :/

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, i managed to change IDs and solved the effect on my project. i'm going to mark this as the solution.

Comment: Glad I could help. jQuery is a little out of style but super useful for DOM manipulations. You can even use it in Node with [cheeriojs](https://cheerio.js.org/). Definitely worth the couple hours it takes to learn for all the utility you get out of it.